# Rails how can I put <%= link_to ...%> into an instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have this (and other) navigation links:

```
<li><%= link_to "Actors with commas",  actor_path('search')+'/commas' %></li> |
```

These need to be put into the header part of my templates and they change based on the view template.

So in application.html.erb I have this:

```
<div class='submenu'>   
  <%= @app_menu %>
</div> <!-- end submenu -->
```

And in the view template I have:

```
@app_menu =
```

The question is, how do I put the top line (with the link_to, etc) into that instance variable and have Rails parse it properly with the HTML and without errors. Right now if I include `<ul><li>` it prints them out literally. And, of course, if I include <%= link_to... I get all sorts of errors.

Or is there perhaps a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating partials for each menu, so one partial _actors_menu.html.erb might look like this:

```
<%= image_tag "submenu-separation.png", :alt => 'separator' %> <li><%= link_to "Actors with commas",  actor_path('search')+'/commas' %></li> <%= image_tag "submenu-separation.png", :alt => 'separator' %>
<li><%= link_to "Actors with Ampersand (&)", actor_path('search')+'/acute' %></li> <%= image_tag "submenu-separation.png", :alt => 'separator' %>
```

Then I put `@app_menu = "actors_menu"` on each actor view. And so on for the other pages.

But I'm wondering if there is a smarter way to do all this?

Also, where and how would I set a global variable for the app_menu so as not to repeat it in every template?